# How to round value to 2 digits after coma or till first digit greater than 0 in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

I'd like round

- if number is really small round till first digit greater than 0 and then round by 2 digits. Like this:

  **value = 0.00000012344 => rounded_value = 0.00000012**

  **0.0035 to 0.0035**
- 2 digits after coma if it's just random floating number, like this:

  **76.543554 to 76.5**
- else if it's integer, don't do anything

  **100 stays 100**

  **44 stays 44**

  etc

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and I've tried value.round(2) which gives me only 0.00 and this doesn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think number_with_precision is the perfect answer to your question

to have the result you're looking for, you should set the options `:precision => 2` and `:significant => true`

for your given examples, you would use

```
number_with_precision(0.00000012344, :precision => 2, :significant => true)

number_with_precision(0.0035, :precision => 2, :significant => true)

number_with_precision(76.543554, :precision => 2, :significant => true)
```

for further precisions see the rails doc http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision